# why when coverting PNG img to a Bitmap img in android studio, pixels multiply by 3.

Tags: android, bitmap, png

I calculate inSampleSize to use Bitmap decode method to resize large png files.
When creating a this new bitmap and Log info it's width and height with .getWidth() and .getHeight(), its pixels count has grown by 3 relative to its original size.

code: from line 121-204

https://github.com/abisai1221/android-bitmaps/blob/master/png%20to%20bmp

all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would bet on screen density being applied.

Comment: please include the essential parts of the code here.

Comment: I think you were right @Zielony. If you can, please explain this. I am fairly new to android development but would like to learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bet on screen density being applied. When you load bitmaps from resources, you have to put them in right drawable folders, because Android will automatically scale them to match your phone's screen density. Each folder should contain only images for one specific density. For example, if you have a high density screen in your phone, you should put images in drawable-hdpi folder to get them without scaling. If you're getting 3 times larger images, you probably have a very dense screen, like Nexus 5 or recent Galaxy S phone. To disable scaling, put images in drawable-nodpi folder.

Answer (score 0):

I saw another post of resizing issues and came across the ".inScaled" field of BitmapFactory.options.

This executes by default to scale bitmap to target density.

I set this field to false to prevent it from executing and the images come out perfectly, tho Im still confused as to why it scales the image by a factor of 3.